# What is the easiest way to find MetaPost definitions?

Tags: metapost

What I currently do is that I just use `grep` to search all files in the MetaPost tree for a keyword, e.g.

```bash
grep -r withdots `kpsexpand -v '$TEXMFDIST'`/metapost
```

and then scan the output by eye to find the definition.

In TeX it is a little easier.  I can just use `\show\section` in my document to get the definition of the macro `\section` in the log or I can use the `texdef` tool.

**Is there something similar to `\show` or `texdef` for MetaPost?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know any equivalent of `texdef`, but the [MetaPost manual](https://www.tug.org/docs/metapost/mpman.pdf) mentions a few such commands in its *Debugging* section (around page 73 in my version). `showvariable` does show macro definitions, unfortunately they are truncated to a nominal line length and I couldn't find how to disable this truncation:

```
showvariable thelabel;
```

gives this on the terminal:

```
thelabel@#=macro:(EXPR3)(EXPR4)->begingroup.save.p;picture.p;if.picture ETC.
```

However, I've found a way (admittedly less convenient!) to get the full definition:

```
tracingonline := 1; % to get output on the terminal, not only in the log file

begingroup;
  interim tracingmacros := 1;
  save myPic;
  picture myPic;
  myPic := thelabel.lft(nullpicture, (0,0)); % form a valid expression with thelabel
endgroup;
```

The `begingroup`, `interim`, `save myPic`  and `endgroup` are only there to avoid disturbing code you might have after that (thus, `tracingmacros` and `myPic` will be restored to their previous values after the group; `tracingmacros` is handled with `interim` because it's an internal variable, contrary to `myPic`; you can see variables being restored with `tracingrestores := 1;`).

With this code, I obtain:

```
thelabel@#(EXPR3)(EXPR4)->begingroup.save.p;picture.p;if.picture(EXPR3):p=(EXPR
3)else:p=(EXPR3)infont.defaultfont.scaled.defaultscale.fi;p.shifted((EXPR4)+lab
eloffset*laboff(SUFFIX2)-(labxf(SUFFIX2)*lrcorner.p+labyf(SUFFIX2)*ulcorner.p+(
1-labxf(SUFFIX2)-labyf(SUFFIX2))*llcorner.p))endgroup
(SUFFIX0)<-
(SUFFIX1)<-thelabel
(SUFFIX2)<-lft
(EXPR3)<-picture
(EXPR4)<-(0,0)
```

I wouldn't say it is gorgeous, but now it *looks* like the macro definition. One can add a moderate amount of automation:

```
vardef displayMacros(text t) =
  interim tracingmacros := 1;
  t;
enddef;

displayMacros(
  save myPic;
  picture myPic;
  myPic := thelabel.lft(nullpicture, (0,0));
);
```

Regarding the `withdots` example you mentioned, you can try this:

```
showtoken withdots;
showvariable withdots;
show withdots;
```

I obtain this:

```
> withdots=tag
withdots=picture
>> Edge structure at line 29:
Filled pen stroke :
(2.5,5)..controls (2.5,5) and (2.5,5)
 ..(2.5,5)
butt ends, mitered joins limited 1 with pen
pencircle transformed (0,0,0,0,0,0)
End edges
```

So, `withdots` is a picture object, not a macro. Compare with the output given above (at the top of this post) for `showvariable thelabel`.